# Why are arrow functions in reactjs sometimes treated as components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm learning reactJS at the moment and I'm finding it hard to understand why are arrow functions in reactjs sometimes treated as components and sometimes just as normal arrow functions.

In this example:

```js
    class CommentListContainer extends React.Component {
      state = { comments : [] };
      componentDidMount() {
        fetchSomeComments(s => // 1- here fetchSomeComments is treated as a normal arrow function
          this.setState({ comments: s }));
      }
      render() {
        return <CommentList comments={this.state.comments} />; // 2- here CommentList is treated as a component
      }
    }

    // 1

    const fetchSomeComments = cb =>
      cb([
        { author: "Chan", body: "You look nice today." },
        { author: "You", body: "I know, right?!" }
      ]);

    // 2

    const CommentList = comments =>
      <ul>
        {
          comments.comments.map(
            (c, index) => (
            <li key = {index}>{c.body}—{c.author}</li>
            )
          )
        }
      </ul>
```

I would like to understand this, and also if CommentList is a component how can it be written as a class with a constructor(props)?

Comment: React has 2 types of components, Class component and Functional component. So the arrow function falls under Functional component.

Comment: Arrow functions are a javascript syntax, and the fact that React allows for functional components just means you can define them using arrow function syntax.

Comment: Yes I understood that now, I'm now finding it hard to convert it to a class component as I don't know how can I parse the comments with a constructor(props), can you recommend me anything to actually understand how it works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arrow function in ReactJS is considered either as a **functional component** or just an *arrow function* depending on what they return.

> ```js
> const CommentList = comments =>
>       <ul>
>         {
>           comments.comments.map(
>             (c, index) => (
>             <li key = {index}>{c.body}—{c.author}</li>
>             )
>           )
>         }
>       </ul>
> ```

The above component is called a **stateless component**. It does nothing but render the props. There is no states, hooks etc.

But the components that can be stateful are made possible with **react hooks**. That is, a functional component can just do everything that a class component does. It can **render states** perform operations and not just return only JSX (like a stateless component)

To understand this in detail, take a look at [React Function Component](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component)

---

To make CommentList a class component, the following can be done:

```
class CommentList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
    }

    render () {
      /* destructuring props so that we can use "comments" prop directly instead of
      using this.props.comments */
      const {comments}=this.props; 

      return (
        <ul>
          {comments.comments.map((c, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {c.body}—{c.author}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
}
```

**TLDR;
Difference between a normal arrow function and a functional component is the return type i.e a functional component returns JSX.**

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot to understand about how to use props.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CommentList extends React.Component {
  construct(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    let list_items = [];
    for(let c of this.props.comments) {
        list_items.push(<li key = {index}>{c.body}—{c.author}</li>);
    }
    return (
      <ul>{list_items}</ul>
    );
  }
}
```

```
function CommentList(props) {
    let list_items = [];
    for(let c of props.comments) {
        list_items.push(<li key = {index}>{c.body}—{c.author}</li>);
    }
    return (<ul>{list_items}</ul>);
}
```

They are the same in React, the second one is called "function components".
[React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)